# Vaadin application working from command line but not in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, glassfish, vaadin

Utilities: IntelliJ, Glassfish server, Vaadin API

EDIT: I should mention that this is my first time using Vaadin

I have a simple Vaadin application that I'm trying to launch as a test. If I run it on the command line (with Maven) and launch it from the Glassfish Applications panel in the admin console, it works perfectly. When I try to use the same code in IntelliJ, I get a 404 error. I want to use IntelliJ for debugging purposes, so it's important that I get it to work from there as well. Here is the code I am using:

```
@Title("test")
@Theme("valo")
public class MyVaadinApplication extends UI {
    private String user;
    private String pwd;

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = false)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinApplication.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        FormLayout form = new FormLayout();
        setContent(form);

        TextField nameField = new TextField("Name:");
        PasswordField passField = new PasswordField("Password:");
        Button button = new Button("Login");

        form.addComponent(nameField);
        form.addComponent(passField);
        form.addComponent(button);

        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                user = nameField.getValue();
                pwd = passField.getValue();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the web.xml (it's pretty empty and irrelevant). From my understanding, if you use the @WebServlet and @VaadinServletConfiguration annotations, you do not need to specify any mappings/servlets in the web.xml file. Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>test</display-name>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And finally my Maven pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gov.bnl.cad</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.4.2</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.source.version>1.8</project.source.version>
    <project.target.version>1.8</project.target.version>
    <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
</properties>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>CAD Repo</id>
        <url>file:///usr/common/jar/cad-repo</url>
    </repository>
    <site>
        <id>${project.artifactId}</id>
        <url>/usr/common/jar/cad-repo/${project.artifactId}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>CAD Repo</id>
        <url>file:///usr/common/jar/cad-repo/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.bnl.cad</groupId>
        <artifactId>pageParser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.bnl.cad</groupId>
        <artifactId>rcs-cad</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                            <mainClass>com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/dashbuilder/styles.scss</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                    <source>${project.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${project.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How did you configure the deploy at the server in IntellIJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Servlet 3+ you don't need to use web.xml at all, given annotations are provided in your code. So you can just delete that file if you want. If you use web.xml it will override your annotated settings.

So delete your web.xml file and change `value = "/*"` to `urlPatterns = "/*"` in `@WebServlet` annotation then try again.

If it still doesn't work, you need to check your IntelliJ run configurations explicitly. Your server might not be configured properly in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I'm still getting the 404 error :/ do you see anything in the pom file that's wrong or missing? I have a feeling I'm just not importing something or not using the right library.

And as far as my server configurations go, everything should be okay. I've used Glassfish on a bunch of other applications and it worked fine. Are there Vaadin-specific things I should be doing/changing?

Comment: I can't see any errors in your Java code and your app runs properly from console so the issue should be IDE specific. You might want to update your servlet version from alpha build to a more stable one but I don't think that will change anything much. Still worth a try though. Other than that your pom.xml seems fine. You could test it on a different IDE like eclipse or different server like Apache Tomcat to narrow down the error possibilities. If IntelliJ doesn't give any compile-time warnings or errors your library imports should be just fine.